How can a scalar particle be differentiated, experimentally, from a vector particle? How can we tell?
For a theoretical particle, especially one that does not interact via the electromagnetic force, how can we tell, physically, whether it has a spin or not?
Or, perhaps, what that spin is?
How is spin (or lack thereof) determined or detected experimentally?

Certainly the decay angular distributions are key. For example:
$$ \pi^0 \rightarrow 2\gamma $$
has to be isotropic, while a vector decay, e.g.:
$$ \rho \rightarrow \pi^++\pi^- $$
depends on the rho's polarization, e.g.:
$$|s, s_z\rangle \rightarrow Y_{l=s}^{m=s_z}(\theta, \pi) $$
Really it's a case by case basis, though, but I don't have any other example at hand.

Firstly, the question is slightly counterfactual. Because it asks for the behaviour of particles that are only theoretical.
Nonetheless there are different cases one can consider

Known particles in the standard model that have no electric charge (such as neutrinos)

So far unkown (theoretical) composite particles with no charge

Particles beyond the standard model


One way, you could in principle distinguish particles with integer spin and half integer spin, is testing if they are fermions or bosons. Assuming the spin-statistic theorem holds, only half integer particles behave as fermions. I.e., they cannot condensate to a Bose Einstein condensate.
Other then that, a more indirect way to confirm the spin of a particle is the development of an (effective) quantum field theory that correctly describes the scattering regime. You can then look at the weight of the $\operatorname{Spin}(1,3)$ representation of the field theory.
In the case of composite particles of charge zero, it could also be possible to analyse their constituents. If they have charge your can "measure" there spin. However, this leaves an ambiguity in how the spins add up in the composite particle (e.g, pions have spin $0$).
